# Setting window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows() to false hides UI and gives Abnormal result

Tags: android

[image: As we can see, Edit text is not displayed]

I am trying new IME Animations present in Android 11 beta. I created one Activity that has following layout as view :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:inputType="text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In onCreate of my Activity class, I set following class :

```
window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

by definition, I am requesting the app to be laid out fullscreen.

But as soon as I add it, View Disappears and a white screen is inflated. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe the content appeared under the action bar (so the content is hidden by the action bar) as `window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)` is supposed to do that. You need to set proper insets for your view to adjust to systems bars as well as the system actionbar.